# PHP and imap_search - how to parse the results?

Tags: php, imap

I am using imap_search to find mails with a certain subject, like this:

```
$connection = imap_open(MAILHOST, MAILUSER, MAILPASSWORD);
$results = imap_search($connection, 'SUBJECT "My subject"');
```

Now I am looping through the results, like that:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $header = imap_fetchheader($connection, $result);
    print_r($header);
}
```

The $header var is a string, is there a nice way to extract for example the Delivered-To part from that string?

Answer (score 1):

This question is too old but for future Googlers:
Try this:

```
$header = imap_headerinfo($connection, $result);
```

[`imap_headerinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php) returns an array of the header values. See the php.net